# Image Viewer for multiple images side-by-side

Tags: windows, image-viewer

I have a recent need/want to view multiple images (e.g. up to 30) side-by at different magnifications, crops, etc. --- For my Windows computer.

I remember back in MS Office 97-XP, there was a software called MS Photo Editor. Each image would launch in its own window (i.e. back then, called MDI - multiple document interface).

Is there a modern equivalent? I tried Irfanview but couldn't get it to work. According to FastStone website, it allows allows 4 images at a time.

Is it my best bet to try and install an old version of MS Photo Editor?

Comment: In what way is this different from opening 30 images, each in its own window? Why do you need any particular support in the image viewer?

Comment: Try PhotoDesktop 1.6 by tenutec.com

Answer (score 2):

I've found PhotoDeamon which up to the 6.0 release supports MDI. After the 6.0 version, they now have a new looking layout which also may work for you.

> ## [PhotoDeamon](http://photodemon.org/) (Open source)
>
> A free, portable photo editor focused on performance and usability. Macro recording and batch processing are
>   key features. English, Dutch, French, German, Italian, Malay,
>   Portuguese, Spanish, and Swedish translations available.

Version 6.0 User Interface
[image: Version 6.0 User Interface]

Version 6.6 User Interface
[image: Version 6.6 User Interface]

#### [Download the 6.0 Version](http://photodemon.org/downloads/PhotoDemon_6.0.zip)

#### [Download the Latest Version](http://photodemon.org/download/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use MulimgViewer. (This is my repository).

MulimgViewer is a **multi-image viewer** that can **open multiple images in one interface**, which is convenient for image **comparison and image stitching**.

MulimgViewer supports **sequential and
parallel mode** to display image.

MulimgViewer is implemented in python and currently provides Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 versions.

Future: The parallel zoom function of the picture is being realized and I believe it will be released soon.

GitHub:
https://github.com/nachifur/MulimgViewer

Wiki:
https://github.com/nachifur/MulimgViewer/wiki

[image: MulimgViewer screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE!  Are you the author or just a happy user?  If the former, please indicate in your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reminder. I have modified it, is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, that looks great!  If you accept pull requests from others, I think it's great to simply indicate that it is your repository.  If you don't, then you can indicate that you are the sole author.  Either way, your project looks very interesting and useful, and I'm hoping to try it myself when I have enough time to look closely at it.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, I used to use an old shareware version of Paint Shop Pro which had a browse feature which tiled images together, allowing me to compare.

Windows also shows images in tiled views, so browse to the directory, and in the view menu, change to small/large/extra large to view the images together.

Answer (score 1):

**Butterfly Viewer** can view multiple images side by side with synchronized panning and zooming. Simply drag and drop image files into it and it'll auto-arrange them as a grid, column, or row.

I'm the creator, and I recently released it to the public on [GitHub](https://github.com/olive-groves/butterfly_viewer).

You can [install it on Windows](https://olive-groves.github.io/butterfly_viewer/butterfly_viewer.html#windows-executable), run it as a [package for MacOS (beta)](https://olive-groves.github.io/butterfly_viewer/butterfly_viewer.html#macos-app), or run it directly on its Python source code.

GIF of drag-and-drop with synchronized zoom and pan
[image: GIF of drag-and-drop with synchronized zoom and pan].

Image of six photos individually panned and zoomed
[image: Image of six photos individually panned and zoomed].

Comment: Welcome Lars!  Thank you for sharing your creation.  It looks very good.

Answer (score 0):

I've found MultiImage Pro which up to the 1.6 release supports MDI. After the 1.6 version, they now have a new looking layout which also may work for you.
Download it at www.imagexsoft.com